# The next corean numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let n be an integer greater than 9 and the fibonacci sequence made with initial terms F($0$) and F($1$)with:

- F($0$)= the sum of the absolute values of difference between adjacent digits in n, and
- F($1$)= the sum of all digits of n.

  And with the usual fibonacci recurrence relation F(n)= F(n-1)+ F(n-2), If n itself appear in that Fibonacci sequence then n is called a corean number. For example with number $150$ we get F($0$)=$9$ and F($1$)=6, and with the fibonacci recurrence relation we get: $$9,6,15,21,36,57,93,(150)$$ Since $150$ itself appear in that fibonacci sequence, then $150$ is a corean number. The first few corean numbers are: $29,49,78,102,150,204$. I conjecture that most corean numbers are multiple of $3$. Can you find a larger example of corean numbers? (especially those coprime with $3$)

Comment: $29, 49, 78, 102, 150, 204, 212, 306, 408, 424, 495, 605, 636, 667, 675, 801, 817, 848, 879, 1076,$ $1186, 2152, 2194, 2398, 2699, 5312, \dots$ Do these numbers tell you anything?

Comment: @Timon, is there a formula for generating these numbers?, Are these numbers given by you successive terms ? it seems that my conjecture is false but it's okay : )

Comment: @Timon, it seems like an answer to me, would you like give the rests of the numbers you've found in answer ? :)

Comment: I do not know any formula generating those numbers; I do not know if they are successive; they are the only numbers I have found. I would be glad to help you, but I cannot do more at the moment.

Comment: Okay thanks Timon : )